# How do you compare the content of an edit control to the text in a file?

Tags: c++, winapi, string-comparison

I am writing a simple text editor using the Win32 API and I am trying to write a function to compare the content of the file to the content of an edit control. I currently have this:

```cpp
BOOL checkForModification (PCWSTR pszFileName, HWND hEdit) {
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    DWORD dwTextLength = GetWindowTextLengthA(hEdit);
    hFile = CreateFile(pszFileName, GENERIC_READ, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            DWORD dwFileSize;

            dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
            if (dwFileSize != 0xFFFFFFFF)
            {
                PSTR pszFileText;

                pszFileText = (PSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwFileSize + 1);
                if (pszFileText != NULL) {
                    DWORD dwRead;

                    if (ReadFile(hFile, pszFileText, dwFileSize + 1, &dwRead, NULL))
                    {
                        bSuccess = TRUE;
                        pszFileText[dwFileSize] = 0; 

                        LPSTR pszEditText = (LPSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwTextLength + 1);
                        GetWindowTextA(hEdit, pszEditText, dwTextLength);

                        int res = CompareStringA(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, NULL, pszFileText, -1, pszEditText, -1);
                        
                        if (res != CSTR_EQUAL) {
                            MessageBox(NULL, L"You changed the text!", L"Alert", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

                        }

                        GlobalFree(pszEditText);
                    }
                    else {
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"Oh no! Something went wrong!\nError code: 2", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                    }
                    GlobalFree(pszFileText);
                }
            }
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Oh no! Something went wrong!\nError code: 1", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    
    return bSuccess;
}
```

The problem that I am having is that the result of `CompareStringA` is always returning `CSTR_LESS_THAN`, even when I don't change the text in the edit control. The encoding of the file is UTF-8. Why is this happening?

Comment: Use a library like [immer](https://github.com/arximboldi/immer) and get the cheapest possible dirty flag tracking there is. If you are writing a text editor you absolutely, positively will want to use immutable data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, use a debugger and test it with a file that contains simple text like **ABCDE**. You should be able to figure out the problem in less than 30 seconds just by inspecting a few variables!

You can trivially determine that the problem is not reading the documentation of function `GetWindowTextA` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta).

The size you pass include the null terminating charaters. Assuming that the edit also contains **ABCDE**, then the length is 5.

Calling  `GetWindowTextA(hEdit, pszEditText, dwTextLength);` where `dwTextLength` will returns a buffer that contains **ABCD** plus the **null character**.

**Obviously ABCD is before ABCDE using usual sorting rules.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for my purposes, I have found it to be easiest to just use the [`Edit_GetModify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-ch/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-edit_getmodify) macro to see if any edits have been made to the text in the edit control. While this doesn't do exactly what I want (it will return `TRUE` even if you undo your changes), it is more efficient than having to read the entire file then compare its entire contents to that of the edit control.

Comment: You also can store original text in another variable, and when you undo your changes you can compare them, if they're the same (it's undone back to its initial self) then you can use [`Edit_SetModify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-edit_setmodify) macro with `FALSE` to prevent future confusion.